# How to allow for cross-project domain mapping in Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-dns

I'd like to manage my application as follows:

- Project A for DNS management,
- Project B for Cloud Run in staging environment,
- Project C for Cloud Run in production environment.

So for example, let's say I manage `mydomain` zone in Project A, with `www.mydomain.com`, `app.mydomain.com` and `staging.mydomain.com` CNAME records configured there.

In Project B I manage one Cloud Run service, `staging-service`.

In Project C I manage two Cloud Run services, `www-service` and `app-service`.

How can I map the services from Project B or C to the domains/subdomains in Project A?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS does not care which projects your resources are in. You can create DNS resource records for supported resources located in any project. DNS is a hostname to IP address translation service.

When mapping custom domains in Cloud Run, you will be presented with DNS resource records to create. Those records are IP/CNAME based.

[Mapping custom domains](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains)

Your will first need to verify site (domain) ownership for each project that you wish to use custom domains or certificates:

[Verify your site ownership](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=en)

[Cloud Run: Add verified domain owners to other users or service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#add-verified)